# How to add a Selecteditem or Clickevent to a custom calendar?

Tags: c#, wpf, onclick, calendar, selecteditem

I have a custom calendar control which associates text with a date, instead of a DatePicker style of control. This custom control has a class for Day with property Notes:

```
public string Notes
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set
        {
            notes = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Notes"));
        }
    }
```

On the actual Calendar class, I have an event handler:

```
public event EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs> DayChanged;
```

I have a Day_Changed method which triggers the event:

```
private void Day_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "Notes") return;
        if (DayChanged == null) return;

        DayChanged(this, new DayChangedEventArgs(sender as Day));
    }

public class DayChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Day Day { get; private set; }

    public DayChangedEventArgs(Day day)
    {
        this.Day = day;
    }
}
```

And then on the actual form, I can use this created event DayChanged to trigger a method behind the form:

```
 <PersonnelTracker:Calendar x:Name="Calendar" DayChanged="Calendar_DayChanged"/>

 private void Calendar_DayChanged(object sender, DayChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Now, what I am looking to do, is to find a way to be able to select a day or position on the calendar and trigger it to a method behind the form. The complication I am having, is that the calendar control itself doesn't have a click event, meaning one would probably have to be made, yet I can't use `MouseButtonEventArgs`, due to not having an individual object to work with, such as a button.

**Is there any suggestion on how best to do this?**

[image: Calendar Example]
So this is the Calendar, and for those who don't understand, I just need to click on a certain day and it to set off a click event, yet like I stated before, this calendar control doesn't have one yet, and therefore I am looking for the best possible way to create such.

The only extra details I can put forward, are that you can go through each day item in turn such like this:

```
foreach (Day item in Calendar.Days)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... what do you mean by '*to select a day or position on the calendar and trigger it to a method behind the form*'? Please also describe, or add an image detailing what your control looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the way that I see this working is simple. Either, you use a `Button` for each 'day' in the calendar, or you use one of the `PreviewMouseDown` events on whatever element each day is currently composed of.

Personally, I'd rather go with the `Button`, or thinking about it further, a `ToggleButton` would be even better. The `ToggleButton` has the `IsChecked` property which you could bind to the `Background` property using a converter, or maybe even just a `Trigger`. That way, you could easily highlight the selected day.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand for the most part. When you say, add a button for each day. Do you mean I should physically add a button on each square or making each square/day a button?

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that each square could be a `ToggleButton`, but using a `Style` that makes it appear as a plain square.